# Change values to null in Marshmallow, Python [PUT] request

Tags: python, python-3.6, put, nonetype, marshmallow

Quite new with Marshmallow and have come across an issue regarding updating values in the database to be null when sending a PUT request to an API. Here is an abridged version of my schema:

```
class FeatureSchema(Schema):
    id = mfields.Integer()
    name = mfields.String()
    description = mfields.String()
    status = mfields.String()
    fields = mfields.List(mfields.String)
    feature_file = mfields.Int()
    type = mfields.String()
    imputation = mfields.Integer()
    scaling = mfields.String(allow_none=True)
```

and my update Feature method:

```
 def __init__(self):
     self.mm_schema = FeatureSchema()

 def update(self, id, name=None, description=None, fields=None, feature_file=None, imputation=None,
               template_type_id=None, scaling=None
               none_values_to_set=None):


        feature = drop_keys_with_none_or_empty_values(locals())

        if none_values_to_set:
            for key in none_values_to_set:
                if key in allowed_attributes:
                    feature[key] = None

        url = "{}/api/feature/".format(self._base_url)
        return self._put(url, self.mm_schema.dump(feature))
```

I want to be able to update values to be None, which works fine until the self._put method. The schema dump happens as desired, but the _put method errors with the following error:

```
>>> bc.update(id=1010, scaling=None)
Out[4]: {'error': "{'scaling': ['Field may not be null.']}"}
```

I am using python requests library to create requests.
Marshmallow 3.5.0
Python 3.6

Do let me know if I need to add any more info, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Ähm for me it looks like the api you send the put request to requires this field. So its telling you it cant be null if you ask me. But i dont know the api so I cant tell for sure :)

Comment: Hi @chrisaramar, thanks for replying :) I have checked the api and in the model the field is listed with nullable=True

Comment: Okay is there a documentation? Some apis require specific nulls like "null" or some can handle python Nones. I mean it says Field may not be null so something hast to be wrong with the null if the field says nullable true

Comment: And I dont know where the error could be else but if I translate it correctly to my language it directly says. "Cant be null" so in my opinion its not nullable.

Comment: Or maybe nullable doesnt mean None or null ... maybe it means that if its an integer it can be 0 or if its a string it can be "" you know what i mean?